# Running into errors creating a linked service in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse-analytics

I am trying to create a linked service to Azure Datalake Gen 2 using SAS URI. I was able to sucessfully create the required SAS Token that has all the permissions for a particular container.

Under the linked service configurations, I am using the following options:

> Authentication Type: SAS URI

> SAS URL:https://.blob.core.windows.net/

> SAS Token: The token that was generated with all the permissions available, for a container

When I try testing the connection, it throws up an error:

> ADLS Gen2 failed for forbidden: Storage operation '' on container 'testconnection' get failed with 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden''. Possible root causes: (1). Please check storage network setting whether public network access is disabled. If disabled, use Managed Virtual Network IR and create Private Endpoint to access. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private (2). It's possible because some IP address ranges of..

The Datalake instance has been configured with following network options:

> Firewall:Enabled for all networks

> Network Routing: Microsoft Network Routing

not sure why it keeps throwing the error

Comment: I don't know much about the Microsoft Network Routing, but did you select that in the SAS generation as well? Also, for the URL base, try https://youraccount.dfs.core.windows.net instead of https://youraccount.blob.core.windows.net

Comment: I tried both but i am still getting the same error. when i was creating the token in the azure portal, at a container level, I was not getting any options to configure networking.

Comment: On the portal SAS screen, it's near the bottom, labeled "Preferred routing tier".

Answer (score 2):

I tried to replicate the issue in my environment with below storage account networking settings:

[image]

Created linked service with SAS URI authentication and tested the connection I got the same error:

[image]

I enabled `Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account` by selecting   Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses

[image]

After enable of `Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account` select Enabled from all networks. when tested the connection of linked service it tested successfully.

[image]